# Is there any way to download MySQL database information to SQLite

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm new to android development and creating a simple android application which interacts with the web server. I want to download MySQL database data to SQLite database and then, the android application using this SQLite database information. Is it possible to do that ?? Are there any tutorials for that?

please help. thanks

Comment: Using Webservices, you can do this. Create a webservice which will read the data from mysql server and return it in Json format, From the phone read this Json string and store it in sqlite :)

Comment: i know the way to return mysql data as json format.but i don't know way to read json data using phone and store it in sqlite.are there any tutorials to do this?

Comment: Check the following answer links.

Answer (score 0):

yes, is it possible, you need to learn the way to take data from your database, you can follow  these example :

[Send and Receive JSON between Android and PHP Web Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php)

[Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

the way to put your json to SQLite such as like this :

```
Helper helper=new Helper(this);

JSONObject spinner = PRODUK.getJSONObject(i);
                                            String LSBS_ID = spinner.optString("LSBS_ID");
                                            String LSBS_NAME = spinner.optString("LSBS_NAME");
                                        helper.InsertSpin_Produk(LSBS_ID, LSBS_NAME);

    public void InsertSpin_Produk(
                String LSBS_ID, String LSBS_NAME
                ) {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put("LSBS_ID",  LSBS_ID);
            cv.put("LSBS_NAME",  LSBS_NAME);
            getWritableDatabase().insert("spinner_produk", null, cv);
        }
```

Comment: You could post links as a comment or explain them in details instead of posting just links. Otherwise your answer will be flaged as `link-only answer` and will be deleted.